# How to findout checked values in the following html using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
Here is my HTML:
<ul>
   <li ng:repeat="category in categoriesList">
    <a>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-init="isChecked = checkCategory(category)" ng-model='isChecked' checked="isChecked" ><font>
      {{category.name}}</font></a> 
   </li>
   <li>
    <a ng-click='upadteCategoryDetails()'>Apply </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

while clicking apply need to update checked categories. If anyone know means please update me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will done inside your controller, you should help with the code you have for it so far. One general comment is that it would help to use ng-model in the checkbox like category.checked and a filter in the controller with a function to return checked values.

Comment: yeah. Am asking sample code for retreiving checked values.

Comment: what does `checkCategory()` do? I totally agree with @alou, get rid of `ng-init` creating a primitive in the repeated child scope

Comment: checkCategory() --> I used for  that category is available or not in my list. That is working fine. I need while clicking apply i need available checked categories.

Comment: There is no need for apply, if you are using scope variable <-2 way binding-> ng-model, you are in Angular world so get the most of it.

Comment: That is ok. But requirement is while clicking apply need to do bulk update.

Comment: `bulk update` what?  You haven't provided enough information in question to see what your goal even is. Get rid of the primitives as models as suggested will definitely help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler if you bind the checkbox to a property inside the category object itself, then your Apply can cycle through and gather the categories that are checked and do whatever you want with them.

Here is a working plunker as an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/TabolQ9G3Z3HBm920KaZ?p=preview

```
 <li ng-repeat="category in categoriesList">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="category.isChecked" checked="category.isChecked">
    <font>{{category.name}}</font>
 </li>
```

And the controller function:

```
  $scope.upadteCategoryDetails = function(){
    var selectedCategories = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.categoriesList.length; i++){
      if($scope.categoriesList[i].isChecked)
        selectedCategories += $scope.categoriesList[i].name + ', ';
    }

    $scope.selectedCategories = selectedCategories;
  };
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

ng-model is used inside ng-repeat its better if you have this isChecked within category json itself

```
 <ul>
   <li ng:repeat="category in categoriesList">
    <a>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-init="category.isChecked=true" ng-model='category.isChecked' checked="category.isChecked" ><font>
      {{category.name}}</font></a> 
   </li>
   <li>
    <a ng-click='upadteCategoryDetails()'>Apply </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then in updateCategoryDetails you can get categories which are checked with isChecked field.